# SVN web authentication by MySql

Tags: mysql, apache, svn, authentication, mod-dav-svn

I want to do authentication for my SVN server through Apache Web Server by mod_dav_svn. Authentication users I want to use MySql since later I want to extend other functions later on.

I've follow this instruction and it's working out correctly and perfect for me 
[SVN Authentication using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164032/svn-authentication-using-mysql)

But what happen since I want to define group of user with read-only and other groups read-write permission.

I'm out of ideas so please help me :) .

PS: AuthzSVNAccessFile dynamic editing would take too much of effort :'(

Comment: Which module did you pick? The referenced question lists two.

Comment: mod_authn_dbd ... the reference said that the other one was stop updated since 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have read if you are going to use the open source subversion server, your options are limited to modifying the access file as you were hesitant to do.

The issue is mentioned here, although in regards to LDAP auth: https://serverfault.com/questions/188023/webinterface-for-configuring-svn-access-in-mod-dav-svn

My advice is to set up a cron job to automatically generate the auth file on a regular interval.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question ???
Actually now other ways ??? such as using Limit or LimitExcept ???

Comment: Perhaps you could provide access to the same repository through two different URLs, one read only and one read/write.  The SQL queries used to authorize users for each could be different (and include a group check)